# Android src: Why is it shown as folder in some projects and package in other?

Tags: android, eclipse, directory, src

In my current Eclipse config, src folder is not displayed the same way everywhere!

As you can see on screenshot below, com.WazaBe.BePlanes is shown as a package and tof.cv.mpp is shown as folder...

I really would like to understand where it went wrong and fix that.

Thank a lot for any help!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is likely with configuring the `build path` of the `eclipse project`.
Do this:

```
select the src folder > right click it > "Build Path" > "Use as Source Folder"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because your in the package explorer tab of eclipse. Go to Window -> Show view -> navigator. I believe this is the tab you are looking for.